# py2exe and email libs again

Tags: python, py2exe

Following imports:

```
import pyodbc, sys, smtplib, os
from datetime import date
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
import email.iterators
import email.generator
from email import Encoders
```

Works ok when creating exe with py2exe in Python2.6 but does not in Python2.5

> The following modules appear to be missing
>   ['email.Encoders', 'email.Generator', 'email.Iterators', 'email.MIMEText', 'email.Utils', 'email.base64MIME']

Setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, glob
import modulefinder

modulefinder.AddPackagePath("mail.mime", "base")
modulefinder.AddPackagePath("mail.mime", "multipart")
modulefinder.AddPackagePath("mail.mime", "nonmultipart")
modulefinder.AddPackagePath("mail.mime", "audio")
modulefinder.AddPackagePath("mail.mime", "image")
modulefinder.AddPackagePath("mail.mime", "message")
modulefinder.AddPackagePath("mail.mime", "application")

setup(
    console=['capfile_tester.py'],
    options = { "py2exe": { "includes": "decimal, datetime, email" } })
```

I thought i fixed a problem but unfortunately i have to try python2.5.

Answer (score 2):

Py2Exe has a lot of bugs when compiling various modules inside the exe. I had this kind of problem myself. My suggestion is to use pyInstaller which in my opinion is a lot better and easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue with email module. Even though it gives warning that lot of modules are missing but when I run, I face only two issues: one with multipart and other with text. I got it working by explicitly including these 2 modules in setup.py:

**OLD setup.py contained:**

```
setup(console = ['main.py'])
```

**New setup.py contains:**

```
setup(console = ['main.py'], 
      options={"py2exe":{"includes":["email.mime.multipart","email.mime.text"]}})
```